Flutter Error Method not found FallThroughError throwFallThroughError
I am working in a already developed project and unable to install the application.
And getting this error
 Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.

 - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.7.0/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.

        throw FallThroughError();

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.2/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.

      throw FallThroughError();

            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Dependencies I am using:
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.1
firebase_core: ^1.12.0
firebase_storage: ^10.2.7
firebase_database: ^9.0.6
firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
cloud_firestore:

Sdk: >=2.12.0 <3.0.0
And when I update the cloud Firestore it's telling me that I can't run this project with that version as it's for SDK 2.12.0.
